# Android Shape: Circle with cross(plus)

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to get a circle with a cross(plus) in the middle, like the following:

[image]

Most of the tutorial I've been reading have no helped at all at layer-lists. Here is my code so far:

```
<item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="line">
        <stroke android:width="10dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/bus_red" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="90" >
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke android:width="10dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/bus_red" />
            </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>

<item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp">
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:innerRadius="20dp"
        android:thickness="5dp"
        android:useLevel="false">

        <solid android:color="@color/bus_red" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

As you can see I have a ring shape and two line shapes, one of which I am trying to rotate. The ring shape is of no problem, I am having trouble getting the two lines in the middle, or even getting them to show.

Comment: Why not use rectangles without rotation?

Comment: @jyoon That was my first approach, I didn't get that to work either :/ I don't know how to center the lines.

Comment: `android:gravity="center"` or something like that will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a RelativeLayout:

```
<View
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_add"/>
```

circle_add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp">
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval" >
            <solid
                android:color="@color/bus_green" />
            <size
                android:width="30dp"
                android:height="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="10dp" android:left="17dp" android:bottom="10dp" android:right="17dp">
        <shape>
            <stroke android:width="0dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
            <padding android:left="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp" />
            <corners android:radius="0dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="17dp" android:left="10dp" android:bottom="17dp" android:right="10dp">
        <shape>
            <stroke android:width="0dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
            <padding android:left="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp" />
            <corners android:radius="0dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 21):

I accomplished something similar (a solid circle with a white plus in the middle) using this drawable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/accent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="@android:color/white" />
         </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="-90">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="@android:color/white" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this approach is still valid since it still uses `drawable` in XML.

You can create new vector asset named `add circle outline` in Android Studio.

This is the code it generates:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M13,7h-2v4L7,11v2h4v4h2v-4h4v-2h-4L13,7zM12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM12,20c-4.41,0 -8,-3.59 -8,-8s3.59,-8 8,-8 8,3.59 8,8 -3.59,8 -8,8z"/>
</vector>
```